# UDP Multicast: received by computer but not by application

Tags: c, linux, sockets, multicast

I'm trying to set up an application on Linux to receive MIDI data over UDP multicast via WiFi.

Wireshark shows that the packets sent from the MIDI controller are received by my machine ([paste from wireshark](http://pastebin.com/b1Vb8HAh)).

The source code from the utility I'm using to listen for network traffic and produce ALSA midi events (called [multimidicast](http://llg.cubic.org/tools/multimidicast/)) sets up listening sockets like [this](http://pastebin.com/RVAn8XDW). Basically it sets up 20 sockets, binds them to ports 21928-21948, calls `setsockopt()` with IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP to the group for "225.0.0.37", and then starts listening. This is, as far as I can see, in line with all tutorials and advice on how to listen for UDP multicast traffic.

However, the utility does not receive data.

If, from my PC, I send packets to the relevant ports on "225.0.0.37" (`s.sendto("hello", ("225.0.0.37", 21928))` in Python), the tool still doesn't receive the data. If I send to the ports on localhost (`s.sendto("hello", ("", 21928))`), it *does* receive the data.

I've been reading and experimenting quite a lot, but I can't work out what it is I'm missing. I'm not even sure whether it's an error in the code I'm using or in my box's configuration.

Could anybody shine any light on this?

Comment: Do you specify network interface when running this? Does that match interface where multicast data arrive on?

Comment: This reads as if the app to receive data only listens on `127.0.0.1` but not on other interfaces. Use `netstat` to see on which interfaces the application actually is listening.

Comment: I have tested both with and without specifying interface (as an aside, does INADDR_ANY mean listening on *all* interfaces, or the "default" interface, and how would I find out my default interface?).


`netstat -u` and `netstat | grep 21928` (21928 is the port used) both return nothing. `netstat -g` reports that there are 20 sockets in the "225.0.0.37" group listening on wlan0, which is the interface the packets are received on.

Comment: Hope its not too late..but can you share your python sample code which is not receiving any data ?Also provide the output of "ifconfig" command